# Type mismatch: Cannot Convert From Void to String in Java

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am creating a program for class that replicates Mannings Calculator for river flow using formulas, ifelse, variables, and dialog boxes for messages and inputs. I have most of the program created, i.e. the formulas, variables, some ifelse statements, but I am having an issue related to displaying a resultMessage variable as a JOptionPane message box. I am concatenating output from several Double type variables mixed with some strings, this is what it looks like:

```
resultMessage=JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "At a depth of "+enteredDepth+"ft the flow is "+ calculatedFlow+" cubic ft per second."+"\n"+ "Difference:"+difference);
```

This is giving me the error message as stated in the title. I am unsure what would cause this, it is the only concatenated section in my code, I wanted to quickly type this in as so not have to worry about it later. Some the of variables in the concatenation have not been formulated but that still shouldn't throw the error, IMO. My entire program is as follows:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ManningCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("##.00");

        //Assigned Constants

        final double MANNING_COEFFICIENT = 1.486;
        final double COEFFICIENT_BRICK = 0.015;
        final double COEFFICIENT_CONCRETE=0.012;
        final double COEFFICIENT_ASPHALT= 0.016;
        final double COEFFICIENT_GRAVEL= 0.023;
        final String MATERIAL_BRICK= "Brick";
        final String MATERIAL_CONCRETE="Concrete";
        final String MATERIAL_ASPHALT="Asphalt";
        final String MATERIAL_GRAVEL="Gravel";
        final double TOLERANCE= 0.01;

        //input Variables

        int attemptNumber;
        double desiredFlow;
        double maxDepth;
        double width;
        double roughnessCoefficient;
        double deltaHeight=0;
        double deltaLength=0;
        double enteredDepth;
        double calculatedFlow;
        double difference;
        double minError;
        String resultMessage="";

        //Math variables

        double channelVelocity=0;
        double hydraulicRadius=0;
        double channelArea=0;
        double channelSlope=0;
        double wettedPerimeter=0;

        //JPane for input variables

        desiredFlow=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter desired flow"));
        maxDepth= Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the maximum depth"));
        width= Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width"));
        roughnessCoefficient=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter choice for roughness coefficient:"+
            "\n"+"1 Brick"+"\n"+"2 Concrete"+"\n"+"3 Asphalt"+"\n"+"4 Gravel"));
        deltaHeight=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the change in channel height"));
        deltaLength=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the change in channel length"));
        enteredDepth=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Attempt1"+"\n"+"Enter a depth:"));


        //If else if statements

        if(roughnessCoefficient==1) {
            roughnessCoefficient=COEFFICIENT_BRICK;
        }else if(roughnessCoefficient==2) {
            roughnessCoefficient=COEFFICIENT_CONCRETE;
        }else if(roughnessCoefficient==3) {
            roughnessCoefficient=COEFFICIENT_ASPHALT;
        }else {
            roughnessCoefficient=COEFFICIENT_GRAVEL;
        };

        if(desiredFlow<0 ) {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Desired flow must be greater than 0");
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Desired flow not valid."+"\n"+"The program terminates");
        };

        if(enteredDepth<0.0) {
            if(enteredDepth>maxDepth) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entered depth is not valid."+"\n"+"Desired depth is set to 10.0");
                enteredDepth=maxDepth;
            }
        }

        //Math Formulas
        desiredFlow=channelVelocity * channelArea;
        channelVelocity= (MANNING_COEFFICIENT /roughnessCoefficient) *
                Math.pow(hydraulicRadius, (2/3)) *Math.pow(channelSlope, (1/2));
        hydraulicRadius =channelArea/wettedPerimeter;
        channelSlope=deltaHeight/deltaLength;


        resultMessage=JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "At a depth of "+enteredDepth+"ft the flow is "+
                calculatedFlow+" cubic ft per second."+"\n"+ "Difference:"+difference);

    System.exit(0); 

    }
}
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the exact error, complete with stack trace. Also, please try to format your code. Highlight it, and press ctrl+k while editing to have it format it for you.

Comment: I am trying to add a screen shot of the error code but this comment box won't allow me to.

Comment: Also, I don't know what that CTRL + K command did, but any other red lines I had in my code are gone now?

Comment: Always post errors as text, and always edit it into the question. Pictures are searchable, and text in the comments is messy. Also, someone appears to have answered your question anyways.

Comment: ctrl+k auto-indents all the code by 4 spaces, which tells the site to format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
resultMessage = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "At a depth of + enteredDepth + "ft the flow is " + calculatedFlow + " cubic ft per second." + "\n" + "Difference:" + difference);
```

to

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "At a depth of " + enteredDepth + "ft the flow is " + calculatedFlow+" cubic ft per second." + "\n" + "Difference:" + difference);
```

The problem is `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` has no return value (in parlance it has a `void` return type). As such you can't assign the value of such call to a variable.

Comment: So, using this method will yield the same outcome as if I set it to the variable (minus the error code), as in, it will still be performed last after all other operations have completed?

Comment: @Jkeef: it will be completed after all other operations because it appears after all those other operations. A function/method in Java is run from top to bottom (obeying whatever flow-control structures exist there). The `resultMessage=` portion of the line has no bearing on when the line of code is executed.